# How to check whether give images are bimodal or not using Python

Tags: python, image-processing, histogram

Suppose I have this image [image: Fig]

I would like to check whether this image is a bimodal or not. How to do this using Python? After a couple of google searches, I found out that obtain in bimodal images, it's supposed to have two dominant peaks in the histogram. But not getting any idea how to replicate this into Python. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited. I am basically trying to find whether my image is biomodel are not,  I found some description in this link: https://www.quora.com/What-are-bimodal-images

Comment: But not getting an idea how to do this using Python

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=check+for+bimodal+distribution